# iPhone Shows Gray Area With Arrow To Pull App Back Up

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface

My iPhone sometimes enters a weird state, which I can't make sense of. Just out of the blue, the app drops by a third of the screen height and shows a gray area with a little arrow indicator which allows me to pull it back up. What is this state supposed to represent; what's it good for? I cannot come up with an idea why that should be useful and I don't really know how I initiate this weird behaviour purposely. People I asked what that's this supposed to be good for are at a loss, too but usually wonder why one would question it. Did Apple engineering consider that to be a feature or is it a bug?

[image: Image below shows weird state]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it’s the reachability feature, added to make life easier for people with bigger phones.

On iPhones with notches it’s activated by swiping down on the home indicator, on iPhones without the notch it’s activated by double tapping (not pressing) the home button.

You can deactivate this behavior in Settings under Accessibility -> Touch.

Comment: When the larger screens came out, the one-handed-ness was a concern. But in today's screen sizes, users find this confusing. This year, I started carrying a 6s for testing, while sticking to the smaller SE (original), and this feature confused me a lot.